# New Google Maps Markers Not loading in IE

Tags: java, php, mysql, google-maps

I have a Google Map that displays markers that are stored in a mysql database and Google Maps java API. A user can submit their location which adds a new row in the database and a new marker on the map.

In Chrome and FF, the new marker is displayed after the form is submitted, but when a user submits the form in IE, the new marker is not displayed, even after the page is manually refreshed. IE keeps reusing the same now-outdated version of the map.

how can i force IE to completely refresh everything on the page?

Comment: 1) You should supply your code, so we can see what's going on, 2) are you getting any errors? (use IEs developer tools to check). And 3) Yes, you can refresh everything by reloading the page, but since that doesn't work when you do it manually, it won't work if you do it via javascript either. And since reloading doesn't work, my guess would be that the new marker's data is never sent anywhere, and thus never placed in the database. Since it works in other browsers, it's probably a javascript issue on your page

Answer (score 1):

In the map code, find “iwloc=A&” and remove "A" from the value.  This prevents the white address bubble
from loading (solution courtesy of William Duffy).  Now the red pointer will load.  You can click on the pointer to show the white address bubble.  Not perfect, but at least the location appears on the map now.